# Why does my NAT setup only work properly from time to time?

Tags: networking, iptables, nat

Homework assignment...

There are 3 computers in a local network: `192.168.0.185` (the 'client'), `192.168.0.129` (the 'gateway') and `192.168.0.81` (the 'server'). The 'server' is running a HTTP server, so typing `192.168.0.81` in a browser's address bar from any of the other two computers displays a webpage.

The assignment is to set up NAT in the so-called 'gateway' in such a way that typing its IP address (`192.168.0.129`) in the 'client's browser will display the webpage served by the 'server'. This is my solution attempt:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward

iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.129 --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.81:80
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.81 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.129:80
```

This (I hoped) would make the 'gateway' redirect requests made to it to the 'server' (DNAT) while substituting source address of the request to its own so that the 'server' will correctly send the response through the 'gateway' and not straightly to the 'client' (SNAT).

I typed the 'gateway's IP in the 'client's browser's address bar. Hooray! I saw the webpage! I thought I was done!

Except I wasn't. I then reloaded the page on the 'client'. And I got timeout error. I reloaded the page once again. Timeout again. I waited a teeny tiny bit and reloaded once again. This page the webpage was served correctly. So I reloaded for the final time and... timeout.

This confuses me. It seems that once a page is served things stop working for a while. Why is that happening? Where is my mistake?

I should note that typing the 'server's address in the 'client's browser (as opposed to typing the 'gateway's address) does not cause such problems.

Comment: could be a problem with the web server

Comment: @jsotola I don't think so; please see the edited question.

Comment: @jsotola Because the assignment says I have to configure the 'gateway' in such a way to make this possible.

Comment: The way to debug this is to use `tcpdump` or `wireshark` on all network interfaces that may be interesting, and look at which packets go where, and what is happening to them. (1) If all 3 computers are connected to a single switch, watch out for ICMP REDIRECT messages which will take the gateway out of the loop. (2) You don't have to use both SNAT and DNAT; the connection tracker will take care of SNAT.

Comment: @dirkt Wrt SNAT: I was trying to remove this and things stopped working completely. I think the server was trying to send its responses omitting the 'gateway' then.

Answer (score 1):

I think I got it finally. The culprit was this line:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.81 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.129:80
```

Things started working when I changed it to this:

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp -d 192.168.0.81 --dport 80 -j SNAT --to 192.168.0.129
```

Not sure why but I have a vague idea that NAT uses ports to identify connections. So specifying only one port was leading into conflicts when there was more than 1 request.

Comment: You nailed it: [NAT HOWTO - Mappings In Depth](https://netfilter.org/documentation/HOWTO/NAT-HOWTO-6.html#ss6.3) see "Implicit Source Port Mapping" and "What Happens When NAT Fails". You can use the `conntrack` command (with options -L or -E) to see what's going on

Answer (score 0):

I have a PC with Debian, serving as router and may share some experience with you.

### Routing

If you are intentionally using host as a router, dont ever do

`echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`

Instead do either:

- `sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`
- `nano /etc/sysctl.conf:`

  - and edit `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`

### Forwarding

Oh I've just noticed that you can offer [following stuff](http://shorewall.net/three-interface.htm) all almost without magic. That's just the production answer - its up to you now to dig inside configurations (google [shorewall sources](http://shorewall.net/Development.html) - then you will know how `iptables` parsers/generators work)

Next I can advise some [webmin](http://www.webmin.com/) web interface to play with it - you access [192.168.0.81:10000](http://192.168.0.81:10000) Now you have no reason to learn command line  - all iptables stuff is now done through web interface! ;) Also read its shell scripts and know now, how production things are working!

### Logging

webmin did all stuff, but if you are on debian and want a console log - just type `apt install iftop` (google `iftop` sources, read, educate)

---

Feel free to like and accept this post, if you found my time and this info useful!

Comment: Why should I never do `echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward`?

Comment: @gaazkam because it has a standart way of defining default-behaviour of defining that at a boot time, having that setting ready "on" and not waiting your custom script or shell to interacting, to run specific router-init stuff at system init!!! Read the answer, stop inventing things alredy invented at century ago))

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't think I'm allowed to use tools like Shorewall or Webmin, just vanilla iptables I'm afraid ;/ Also - Im terribly sorry, but I feel reading source code of these tools is... kind of overkillish if my goal is just to set up NAT for a single time

Comment: those are mutually exclusive things. If you want to learn topic - you have to look at "what to be done as per today" - what binaries and utilities are availble - that's at least. Good if you could examinate their source code, surface level at least

Comment: If you dont want to learn topic - pay a bribe to an educator and never appear here anymore)))

Comment: try shorewall, if you like it - investigate on "how does it works", try webmin, if you like it... so on, man, do you want me to go to your educator and solve that for you< umtimatelly for him? man think for production! what educator is trying to teach you? ultimately learn iptables, you may do everything with it, i just dont want to post here -ready-to-copy-solution! I Spent ENOUGH time not learning everywhere to get the hell out of "how does that shit worked"? Spend sme time in research, that's just good!!!

Comment: While I'm certain that reading the source code of these tools will be very educating, I'm afraid I have to do my assignment on time, and I don't believe I'm able to read and understand the sources of - supposedly - very complicated tools on time. Especially given I also have other assignments at the Uni at the moment. Shooting for deep understanding of a topic is good, but shooting for realistic things is even better - and it is unrealistic to expect to understand everything I'm being taught within a single semester on a level far more advanced than the level of these courses.

Comment: @gaazkam nah, they are NOT comlicated at all, all their goal is to get/assemble/parse/store configs(that is just the thing is required from you) and present in to some web server in HTML format! So if you want to be a programmer - you want to assemble that stuff by yourself in any known-by-you language. Why you ever want to do that by hands but not via web interface?

Comment: Please dont forget to like my question, I've worked 3 hours for it, your question took barely 15 minutes!

Comment: Asking to teach you to properly call `iptables` that is costly - my repetitorship costs some money, everything is PRODUCTION, install shorewall, webmin, look code, learn! Little questions - ask. major questions - pay for your education please!